# Limiting Distribution of Successive Transformations (Improved Approach Yet Incomplete)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

My initial attempt to solve this type of problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4424804/limiting-distribution-with-successive-transformations), however, to not overcomplicate the conversation and prior results, I am starting a clean post with my newest results to this problem.

I am interested in the limiting distribution where a successive transformation is performed in a distribution, $Y$. The transformation is of the form

\begin{equation}
 X_{j+1} = \frac{n_j}{n_j+X_j}
\end{equation}

where $n_j \sim U(0,2)$ such that

\begin{equation}
 Y \sim \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} X_j
\end{equation}

This is similar to a continued fraction that acts as a transformation on a random variate of a distribution. From prior work and from numerical simulations, we observe that the distribution settles down into a stationary form after successive iterations. Reasonable approximations to the stationary distribution are reached after about 4 to 5 iterations already. Below is a visualization of the distribution:

[image]

**Partial Solution**

We can determine that the range of the transformation is $[0,1]$. The next step is to determine which values of $n$ and $X$ can map to which regions within the n-by-X or 2-by-1 region. The graph below is partitioned into "Regions". These Regions are marked as $R_{st}$, where $s$ marks the region where $X_j$ belongs and $t$ marks the region where  $X_{j+1}$ belongs.

By inspecting the 2-by-1 grid, we can divide the region into 7 distinct regions. Those regions in the blue map to the $\left[0,\frac{2}{3}\right]$ region, the region in green maps to the $\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right]$ region, and finally, those regions in the purple map to the $\left[\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}\right]$ region on the $[0,1]$ number line.

[image: Phase Transition Diagram]

To determine how much of each region distribution contributes to the total probability, we need to find the limiting distributions of the transition probabilities. We can understand this as a Markov process where the transition probabilities are the individual areas. Calculating these we get the transition matrix, $\mathbf{T}$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{T} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{9}&\frac{2}{9}&\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{17}{24}&\frac{7}{24}&0\\\frac{7}{8}&\frac{1}{8}&0\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The limiting distribution of $R_1$, $R_2$, and $R_3$, can be found easily then as $\frac{17}{29}$, $\frac{19}{87}$, and $\frac{17}{87}$, respectively.

From the prior work at the aforementioned link, we can determine the distribution between $\left[0,\frac{2}{3}\right]$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
 p_1(x) = \frac{17}{58} \frac{1}{(x-1)^2} I_{\left[0,\frac{2}{3}\right]}(x)
\end{equation}

Now to find the distribution for region $\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right]$, we can leverage $p_1(x)$ with the transformation if and only if $n_j \sim U(3X,2)$ $\forall j$. Doing this provides us with $p_3(x)$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
 p_3(x) = \frac{68}{87 (3 \ln 3 - 2)} \frac{2-2x+(3x-2)\ln\left(3-\frac{2}{x}\right)}{4(x-1)^2(3x-2)}I_{\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right]}(x)
\end{equation}

**Current Challenge: Region 2**

The region $\left[\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}\right]$ presents an additional difficulty as it seems that its distribution is the aggregation of regions 1 and 3. It is not clear to me how to determine $p_2(x)$ and it is here where I would appreciate some insight and perhaps assistance.

I would expect that we should be able to complete a similar transformation using $p_1(x)$ and $p_3(x)$. I would expect that $p_2(x)$ should be the aggregate distribution of the following:

1. Using $p_1(x)$ and the transformation where $n \sim U(2X,3X)$
2. Using $p_3(x)$ and the transformation where $n \sim U(2X,2)$

It seems reasonable but it does not seem to work out.