# Confusion between the equivalence of change of variables formulas

Tags: probability, measure-theory, change-of-variable

In my course we have proven the following result

> Let $g$ is a non-negative measurable function on $G$ with measure $\nu$. Suppose $f: E \rightarrow G$ is a measurable function and that $\mu$ is a measure on $(E, \mathcal{E})$ such that
> $$
> \nu=\mu \circ f^{-1} .
> $$ Then
> $$
> \int_G g \mathrm{~d} \nu=\int_E g \circ f \mathrm{~d} \mu .
> $$

Separetly then, we proved (via a different argument)

> Let $\phi:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable and increasing. Then for any bounded Borel function $g$, we have
> $$
> \int_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} g(y) \mathrm{d} y=\int_a^b g(\phi(x)) \phi^{\prime}(x) \mathrm{d} x .
> $$

For $g$ non negative measurable I should be able to derive the second result from the first since it is more general. However, I am confused with what is going on. Here is how I am thinking about this formulation:

First let us convert the second equation into a measure theoretic formulation:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R} }^{} 1_{(\phi (a), \phi(b))} g \, \mathrm{d} \lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R} }^{} g \circ  \phi * 1_{(a,b)} * \phi' \, \mathrm{d} \lambda 
\end{align*}
where $\lambda $ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R} $. My issue now is that I do not know how to apply the previous part. I need to seek $\mu $ such that
\begin{align*}
\lambda  (A) = \mu (\phi^{-1} (A)).
\end{align*}
But how do I find it?

**Question**: Is it that we can't just derive the second from the first because it is hard to find such a $\mu $ moreover even if we find it it might not be the lebesgue measure as we desired?

**Additional**: If so, when do we use the first? I am aware that one can derive formulas for lebesgue to lebesgue measure, however, the above attempted proof has managed to confuse me.

Could someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The density of a pushforward probability measure: the reciprocal of the Jacobian determinant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642511/the-density-of-a-pushforward-probability-measure-the-reciprocal-of-the-jacobian)

Comment: Hi @KurtG. No this not answer my question. I do not have issues with deriving the formulas separately. What I struggle to understand is what is the bigger picture.

Comment: Bigger picture (?) or derive the second from the first (?) which you boiled down to finding $\mu\,.$ Is that $d\mu$ not obviously $\phi'\,d\lambda\,?$

Comment: It is not obvious to me what is going on with the notation.  In the second we seem to be going from Lebesgue to Lebesgue. I don't quite understand what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: If you set $d\mu=\phi'\,d\lambda\,, d\nu=d\lambda\,,G=(\phi(a),\phi(b))\,, E=(a,b)\,,f=\phi$ is then the second formula not fully compatible with the first?

Comment: One more comment: that measure theoretic formula looks so trivial and simple that as a student I asked myself also the question why there is that big fuzz about change of variables with Jacobians and all that in analysis. I think the reason is that derivatives and Jacobians come in as soon as we have measures that have densities. As I wrote in the first comment of the "duplicate": "I would not take an interest in this question if I had not the same type of riddle every now and then."

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4420980/169085